# EsLint returns the error associated with minimatch module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tsconfig, eslintrc

#### Hi guys, I am getting an error associated with EsLint configuration and the error which he returns makes me stumped. I use Vite to make development more fast and easier.

Below I will attach links to eslint & tsconfig/tsconfig.node json files and package.json.

eslint configuration:
**https://paste.aiogram.dev/enuganiger.typescript**

package.json:
**https://paste.aiogram.dev/vanohofuyu.json**

tsconfig.json:
**https://paste.aiogram.dev/zurawahimi.json**

tsconfig.node.json:
**https://paste.aiogram.dev/cewikegoso.json**

So, I go to my folder where package.json is located and install all dependencies with next command:

```
npm i
```

And after I going to the any js/ts file and nothing is going on my rules were not applied.
I have checked EsLint output and I got next error:

```
[Error - 6:37:22 PM] Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'front\.eslintrc.cjs': Cannot find module 'E:\GITHUB PROJECTS\my_projectname\my_projectname\front\node_modules\minimatch\minimatch.js'. 
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
Referenced from: E:\GITHUB PROJECTS\my_projectname\my_projectname\front\.eslintrc.cjs
Happened while validating E:\GITHUB PROJECTS\my_projectname\my_projectname\front\.eslintrc.cjs
```

He returns error that indicates on that EsLint cannot find "minimatch.js" module, but if you are look in the picture below you can see that in the minimatch module isn't have this file.

[minimatch structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzaoz.png)

package.json (minimatch module):

```
"main": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
```

I was trying to remove node_modules and package-lock.json files but it doesn't help. I also try update modules after I have installed them. I was trying to install different versions of the dependencies.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Don't post links to essential elements of the question and don't post links or embed graphics for items that can be adequately presented textually.